# How to align input and labels horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In the HTML shown below, I want to have the following appearance of the tags

```
label1: input1
label2: input2
label3: input3
```

but what I am getting is something like this:

```
    label1: 
    input1
```

Please let me know how to modify the HTML to achieve the desired results.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <form #form="ngForm" class="clr-form  clr-form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
                <div>
                    <clr-input-container>
                        <label>{{ "DISTANCE_MEASUREMENT.START_LONGITUDE" | translate }}</label>
                        <input
                            required
                            maxlength="25"
                            clrInput
                            [(ngModel)]="selectedSite.name"
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                        />
                    </clr-input-container>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <clr-input-container>
                        <label>{{ "DISTANCE_MEASUREMENT.START_LONGITUDE" | translate }}</label>
                        <input
                            required
                            maxlength="25"
                            clrInput
                            [(ngModel)]="selectedSite.name"
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                        />
                    </clr-input-container>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any css affecting this component?

Comment: What is the css being applied on ````clr-input-container```` and its children?

Comment: @DylanAnlezark the corresponding css file is has not code

Comment: Inspect your element and see if there is some css coming from a global file.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following jsFiddle and see if that helps you find a solution
https://jsfiddle.net/n5m43h8b/3/

All I added was some simple css:

```
clr-input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: @amrmbso01 yes it is a css selector after all

Comment: should i add it as it is or precede it or qualify it with a dot. because i added it but bo effect

Comment: @amrmbso01 If it had no effect i'm guessing it is because 'clr-input0container' has some default styling on it like what @Awais suggested in the comments, you can try one of two things. 1) add !important to `display: block; !important` or 2) change `clr-input-container` to a simple div

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: block;` to your style/css

```
clr-input-container {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
clr-input-container {
    display: block
}
clr-input-container > label,
clr-input-container > input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If this doesn't work. Remove any prior css or add `!important` with inline-block.

Add it to your global styles.css, if you are adding it in component css then add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your @component declarator as shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: i slightly modified the code posted above. i tried your code the results are for the first label and input they are horizontally alligned which is as desired . but for the second label and input, the they are beneath label1 and input1 but label2 is not showing??!

Comment: can you create a fiddle or is there some online link where I can check?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out,

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div>
       <label>{{ "D.START_LONG" | translate }}</label> <input
                    required
                    maxlength="25"
                    clrInput
                    [(ngModel)]="s.name"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                />
      </div>
    
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div>
        <label>{{ "DT.START_LAT" | translate }}</label><input
                    required
                    maxlength="25"
                    clrInput
                    [(ngModel)]="s.name"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                />
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
        html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .flex-container {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .row {
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .flex-item {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: Red;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
    }
```